# How to plot a Spectrogram of an audio file using Third Octave (1/3) Band central frequency instead of default narrow band in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, wav, spectrogram

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot
from scipy.io import wavfile
samplingFrequency, signalData = wavfile.read('someaudiofile.wav')
plot.specgram(signalData,cmap=plot.cm.rainbow_r, Fs=samplingFrequency)
plot.xlabel('Time')
plot.ylabel('Frequency')
```

Here `plot.specgram` is using narrow band to plot the Spectrogram, instead of that i want to use 1/3(third) octave band to plot spectrogram. I am not aware which of the parameter of this `plot.specgram` function I have to change.

**Is there any other python library or any other method through which I can plot Spectrogram using 1/3 octave band using two input ( signaldata/Sample and sampling frequency) ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Python package [python-acoustics](https://github.com/python-acoustics/python-acoustics) has implementations of 1/3 octave bands according to IEC 61260-1.

For plotting you can use [acoustics.Signal.plot_third_octaves](http://python-acoustics.github.io/python-acoustics/reference.html?highlight=plot_third_oct#acoustics.Signal.plot_third_octaves).